# Transforming non-normal to normal distribution and back-transform

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, nonparametric, back-transformation, transform

I would like to transform non-normal distribution to normal distribution, and back-transform to its original state (or at least close to the original state).

From this [article](https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/tips-recognizing-and-transforming-non-normal-data/), I've read that you can transform the distribution in to normal distribution by using Box-Cox method.

Question 1: How do I choose lambda parameter for Box-Cox function? In the article, it seemed that the author chose lambda parameter that minimizes standard deviation of the transformed data.

Question 2: How do I know if the transformed data is a good fit of the actual data? What should I do if its not?

Question 3: How do I back-transformed data into its original shape? I understand that there will be distortion within the back-transformed data.

Comment: 1. Much of the point of Box-Cox is that it estimates the transformation parameter for you. Best not to treat the results slavishly. If $\lambda$ is reported as say $-$0.08 or 0.1, use logarithms. 2. Success can be assessed by a normal quantile (probability) plot after transformation. 3. No point to this: you still have the original data.

Comment: For question #2, I would argue that the whole point of doing a transformation is to wind up with new values. After all, if you wanted to get a good fit of the actual data, you have the actual data!

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> 1. Much of the point of Box-Cox is that it estimates the transformation parameter for you. Best not to treat the results
>      slavishly. If λ is reported as say −0.08 or 0.1, use logarithms. 2.
>      Success can be assessed by a normal quantile (probability) plot after
>      transformation. 3. No point to this: you still have the original data.

– Nick Cox